# Independence of Events in Lovasz Local Lemma

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory, independence

> Let $G$ be a (finite) graph with maximum degree $d$ and vertices $v_{1}, \dotsc ,v_{n}$. Let us associate an event $A_i$ with $v_i (i = 1, . . . , n)$ and suppose that $A_i$ is independent of the set $\left\lbrace A_{j}\mid (v_{i},v_{j}) \in E (G) \right\rbrace$.  Let $v_2 , \dotsc , v_q$ be the points adjacent to $v_1$. Prove that 
>   $$
> P(A_{1} \mid \bar{A}_{q+1}\cdots\bar{A}_{n})=P(A_{1})
> $$

Note: This is an intermediary step in [Lovasz local lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lov%C3%A1sz_local_lemma). I just cannot figure out its proof. You can see it [here on page 617](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxt6xSsOfQMkOVk4LU1ZZ0kxdTQ/view).

Comment: Your google drive document currently needs permission to access. You should make it more easily viewable.

Comment: Thanks for notifying. I have changed the settings, now everyone can access it.